# moving sites on apache2

Tags: apache

I have three live sites, and they were in my /home/user/www directory. I decided I would rather they reside in the /var/www directory.

I changed the virtual host Document root to reflect the change. changed from /home/kb2tfa/www/site to /var/www/site.

I reloaded apache2 and got a warning that one of the sites document root is still reflecting to the old path.

something is stll seeing the old path and I don't know what it is because the virtual hosts were changed and two of the sites work.

any ideas on what i"m missing?
Ron G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the string "DocumentRoot" under your apache configuration dir. This can be done easily using the following CLI command while inside your apache config dir:

```
grep "DocumentRoot" *
```

This should indicate which DocumentRoot lines you have in your config files and where the old values are hiding. If you can provide more details about your setup, I'd be able to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: thanks Lior that did it. I had the default setup for the old directory. thanks again.